# Which MSDN Library Shipment includes Asp.net MVC help reference?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm an MSDN subscriber (Premium license with VS Pro) but I didn't get any MSDN Library DVD updates for quite a while now. What I miss most is Asp.net MVC help reference. I know I can use web to get info, but that's not an option since I may not be always connected and I'm also used to local library resources.

Anybody knows where to get the latest MSDN Library with latest updates on help resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know [MSDN Library for Visual Studio 2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=7bbe5eda-5062-4ebb-83c7-d3c5ff92a373) doesn't contain recent ASP.NET MVC documentation though it's the latest MSDN Library update.

You could try using [Package This](http://www.codeplex.com/packagethis) utility which creates .CHM and .HXS help files from the content obtained from the MSDN Library or the TechNet Library via the MSDN Content Service.